# How to edit form in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'am trying to create a edit form in my project but my code do not working well. I can't find the error. Maybe somebody help me?
My **views.py** is:

```
@login_required
def szczegoly_pracownik(request, id):
    link_pracownik = get_object_or_404(Cudzoziemiec, id=id)
    return render(request, 'cudzoziemiec/szczegoly_pracownik.html', {'link_pracownik': link_pracownik})

@login_required
def edycja_pracownika(request, id):
    link_pracownik = get_object_or_404(Cudzoziemiec, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        edycja_pracownika = CudzoziemiecForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if edycja_pracownika.is_valid():
            link_pracownik = edycja_pracownika.save(commit=False) 
            link_pracownik.save()
            return render('szczegoly_pracownik', id=link_pracownik.id)
    else:
        edycja_pracownika = Cudzoziemiec(request.user)
    return render(request, 'cudzoziemiec/edycja_pracownika.html', {'edycja_pracownika': edycja_pracownika})
```

the **def szczegoly_pracownik** is responible for getting the details from record
When I click in html file on the button "Edit" the url works ok, because is redirecting me in to the edycja_pracownika.html , but in edycja_pracownika.html i see only the button, without forms.

EDIT:

The form is displaying correctly but is empty - do not load the datas from created record. ANd when i click "Edit" button the Django return me a error

```
ValueError at /konto/pracownik/edycja/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'edycja'
```

**edycja_pracownika.html**

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<form action="." method="post">
    {{ edycja_pracownika.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="float-right">
    <p><input type="submit" value="Edytuj" ></p>
```

2nd EDIT:

The something was moved. I have use the view like this:

```
@login_required
def edycja_pracownika(request, id):
    link_pracownik = get_object_or_404(Cudzoziemiec, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        edycja_pracownika = CudzoziemiecForm(request.POST, instance=link_pracownik)
        if edycja_pracownika.is_valid():
            link_pracownik = edycja_pracownika.save(commit=False)
            link_pracownik.save()
            return render('szczegoly_pracownik', id=link_pracownik.id)
    else:
        edycja_pracownika = CudzoziemiecForm(request.user, instance=link_pracownik)
    return render(request, 'cudzoziemiec/edycja_pracownika.html', {'edycja_pracownika': edycja_pracownika})
```

When I click the edit button, the form loading me properly with filled fields. But when I click the next button Edit to confirm the changes the Django return me a error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'edycja'
```

And the interpretter showing me on line:

```
@login_required
def szczegoly_pracownik(request, id):
    link_pracownik = get_object_or_404(Cudzoziemiec, id=id) ...
    return render(request, 'cudzoziemiec/szczegoly_pracownik.html', {'link_pracownik': link_pracownik})
```

Comment: You have to instantiate `CudzoziemiecForm` class in `else` instead of `Cudzoziemiec` class.

Comment: Why are you passing `request.user` to `CudzoziemiecForm` in the `else` branch?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've overridden the constructor for `CudzoziemiecForm`, it accepts the data you want to pass to the form as the only positional argument. That means to initialize a form with the user's data you should have:

```
edycja_pracownika = CudzoziemiecForm(request.POST)
```

And to create a new form for a GET request you should have:

```
edycja_pracownika = CudzoziemiecForm()
```

Django's documentation provides some [sample view code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#the-view) for you to look at.